# Ошибка при установке Yii2 под linux

Tags: linux, yii2, composer

Подскажите, как корректно установить yii2. Пытаюсь установить с помощью composer - выдает вот такую ошибку:
https://pastebin.com/7nsn5kVs

Как исправить?

Comment: 1. прав не хватате у композера. 2. У вас должны быть поставленны все необходимые экстеншены

Comment: Не самая лучшая идея размещать выхлоп на стороннем ресурсе.